# Can this patent be rejected?

Tags: prior-art-request, patentability, novelty, non-obviousness

I have an Indian (utility) patent pending (filed in November 2014) for a process related to improved aircraft engine type/class. I am thinking of filing a PCT International application for the same (in the remaining 1 month). I have found out recently that the 'general' method/idea (not the specifics) are published in a paragraph in one thesis. My Indian pending patent involves the specific details, like the component which will be used, of going about making the process useful/successful and it gives the best method of implementing it (which is published no where for the specific engine class that I have done). My method of doing a process includes the published 'general' method/idea (as mentioned above) with additions of subsystems. It is to be noted that the principle/process used is a science which is a patent in 2000's. The same patented process when implemented in automobiles, power-plants and specific airplane engines, got patented recently.

I do not know whether to go ahead with filing an international patent. I know that the published thesis includes a general way of doing the process (i.e. the whats/objectives), my pending patent talks about HOWS/ways of doing it with specifics for a specific class of aircraft engines (which has never been patented for this class of engines but have got patented in other class of aircraft engines, automobiles, power-plants, naval application etc.).

I am a PhD student in Aerospace engineering, cannot afford a Patent Attorney as of now, but know the techno-legal parameters of filing a patent application. Please help, I urgently need an advice. I do not want to waste the money by filing international patent application, if potentially it can be rejected.

Also, let me know the right tags to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can it be a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13723/can-it-be-a-patent)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question requires legal advice.